# Conditional JS Redirect

Tags: javascript, php

I am having a problem with php header redirect not working on safari

```
if (!isset($lang))
{
header('Location: http://domain.com/en/home');
}
```

I have read that this could be done with JS fairly simple, but no idea how to do it with the condition if $lang is set.

Should, I just execute the js within the "php if", or there is a better/clever way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: You are writing a php code which runs on backend (server), and you feel that there is a browser issue for redirection. Please elaborate your question, I don't think there is any issue with browser for php redirection.

Comment: You say "Having a problem", but you don't say what that problem is. I simply can't believe that Safari doesn't understand the "Location" header. It's been a part of the HTTP protocol since the late 1980's, so that would be an epic bug!

Comment: The problem is that the website shows for couple of seconds and then Safari says "A problem repeatedly occurred with website...". I did some search and saw that there is/was a problem with php headers and Safari in the past. So, I have a sumed that this is what my problem was as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should stop the php execution if you set a redirect header:

```
if (!isset($lang))
{
     header('Location: http://domain.com/en/home');
     exit;
}
```

Note: for this to work properly, you need to set this header before any other and before setting any `doctype`. Also, the `exit` prevents anything else from being sent to the broswer (content, other headers, etc). Mixing headers can result in unwanted behavior.

Secondly, you can do:

```
if (!isset($lang))
{
     ?>
     <script>
     window.location = "http://domain.com/en/home";
     </script>
     <?php
}
```

Comment: Thanks, somehow I missed the exit part. I guess I should stop working night time :) It is fixed now!

Answer (score 1):

Using `Java Script`

```
if (!isset($lang))
{
  ?>

    <script>
    location.href = "http://domain.com/en/home";
    </script>

  <?php
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [ob_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)

```
ob_start()//Define at the top of the php page.
if (!isset($lang))
{
header('Location: http://domain.com/en/home');
exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `echo` to print HTML tag `<script>`  and put your JavaScript code inside this tag.

```
if (!isset($lang)){
   echo "
       <script>
          window.location = "http://domain.com/en/home";
       </script>
    ";
}
```